# Proving a statement

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, proof-writing

The question is

Prove that if $A\subset B$ and $B\subset C$, then $A\subset C$.

Now the logical equivalence should be

If $p\rightarrow q$ $ \land q \rightarrow r$, then $p\rightarrow r$.

Now I know that the statement "If $A\subset B$ and $B\subset C$, then $A\subset C$." is true.

However, the truth tables for $p\rightarrow q$ $ \land q \rightarrow r$ and $p\rightarrow r$ are not the same.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: It's OK that the truth tables of $p\rightarrow q\wedge q\rightarrow r$ and $p\rightarrow r$ are different. After all, the propositions are not equivalent. All that's needed is for $p\rightarrow r$ never to be false when $p\rightarrow q\wedge q\rightarrow r$ is true. This condition does in fact hold. The analogous set theory statement: $A$ might be a subset of $C$ without it being the case that $A$ is a subset of $B$ and $B$ is a subset of $C$. But it will never be the case that $A$ will fail to be a subset of $C$ while $A$ is a subset of $B$ and $B$ is a subset of $C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**

The truth tables are used when we deal with propositions. With sets, we speak set-Theory language.

Let us prove that
$$(A\subset B \wedge B\subset C)\implies  A\subset C$$

we assume the premisses are true and prove so is the conclusion .

Let $ x\in A$.

$$x\in A \implies x\in B \;because\; A\subset B$$

$$x\in B \implies x\in C \;since\; B\subset C$$

thus, by transitivity,
$$x\in A\implies x\in C$$

So,

$$A\subset C$$

Comment: $cause{}{}{}{}{}$?

Comment: You fail to prove that the two implications, after "Let $x\in A$ proves $A\subset C$, first you need to prove that the two implications, imply $x\in A \implies x\in C$, before "thus" $A\subset C$

Comment: $x\in A$ is p, $x\in B$ is $q, x\in C$ is r.  The two elementwise propositions consist of $(p\to q) \land (q\to r)$

Comment: @amWhy Hello, thanks for the precision. i added some lines. Do you find it ok now.

Answer (score 3):

Is there any particular reason you do not want to do a “normal” set theory proof? For example, you could start by letting $x \in A \subset B.$ Then, this implies that $x \in B$ and $x \in A.$ Since $x \in B$, and $B \subset C,$ then that implies $A \subset C.$

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter if $(p\to q)\land (q\to r)$ is false.  You are are only interested in the case where  $(p\to q)\land (q\to r)$ are true.  If $(p\to q)\land (q\to r)$ is false, but $p\to r$ is true, it is not a problem because that *still* means $(p\to q)\land (q\to r)\implies (p\to r)$ is true (even if $p\to r$ if false).

Compare it to $A \not \subset B; B\not\subset C$ and $A \subset C$.  (Can happen: $A=\{1,2\}, B=\{dog, cat\}$, $C=\{1,2,3\}$.)

Or $A\not \subset B; B\subset C$ and $A\subset C$.  (Can happen: $A=\{1,2\}; B= \{2,dog\}; C=\{1,2,dog\}$.

Or $A\subset B;B\not \subset C$ and $A \subset C$. (Can happen: $A=\{1,2\};B=\{1,2,dog\}; C=\{1,2,3\}$.)

The lines where $p\to q\land q\to r$ and $p \to r$ differ are in red

$\begin{array}\ p &q&r&p\to q&q\to r&(p\to q)\land (q\to r) &p\to r&(p\to q)\land (q\to r) \implies p\to r\\T&T&T&T&T&T&T&T\\ T&T&F&T&F&F&F&T\\T&F&T&F&T&\color{red}F&\color{red}T&T\\ T&F&F&F&T&F&F&T\\F&T&T&T&T&T&T&T\\ F&T&F&T&F&\color{red}F&\color{red}T&T\\F&F&T&T&T&T&T&T\\ F&F&F&T&T&T&T&T\end{array}$

This will correspond to the cases where $A\not \subset B; B\not\subset C$ but $A\subset C$ or where $A\not \subset B; B\subset C$ but